# Accessing HTML elements inside frames from parent document

Tags: javascript, html, css, frames

How can I access HTML elements contained in a frame from the parent document?
I have tried window.frames, contentWindow and parent.frames, but I get all kinds of errors.

Here is the code of the parent HTML file:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Parent HTML file</title>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            alert(window.frames["frame1"].window.getElementsByTagName("input")[0].value);
            alert(document.getElementsByName("frame1").contentWindow);
            alert(parent.frames[0]document.getElementsByTagName("input")[0].value);
        </script>
    </head>
        <frameset cols="50%,50%">
            <frame src="frame1.html" name="frame1">
            <frame src="frame2.html" name="frame2">
                <noframes>
                    <body>
                        <p>Text</p>
                    </body>
                </noframes>
        </frameset>
</html>
```

Comment: and what about `window.frame1` ?

Comment: Firefox: window.frame1 is undefined

Comment: Frames have been removed from HTML5. If this is a new project you should find a different way.

Comment: This is not a serious project, it's just an exercise. I can see the frames, but I cannot access them properly with javascript.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get html inside iframe using jquery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16103407/get-html-inside-iframe-using-jquery)

Comment: This question is about frames specifically and not iframes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`frames` collection or any `input`s don't exist at the time you try to refer them. You can try this:

```
window.onload = function () {
    alert(window.frames["frame1"].document.getElementsByTagName("input")[0].value;
}
```

Notice, that [`frames` collection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.frames) contains `window` objects instead of `frame/iframe` elements.

Comment: It works with getElementsByTagName, but not with getElementsByName.

Comment: Hmm... `getElementsByName()` returns also a [NodeList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList), you need to use `[0]` (or some other index) ... Why don't you give an `id` for the `input`, which value you want to show, and use [`document.getElementById()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementById).