# Pull first paragraph from blog into iframe?

Tags: html, iframe

I am trying to pull the first paragraph from this blog into an iframe and display it's contents. Here is the blog: https://www.baronaonlinepoker.com/blog

How would I pull the first paragraph into an iframe? I currently have this code but it only displays upper left corner. It needs to be width="180" height="135". Here's the code!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<iframe src="https://www.baronaonlinepoker.com/blog" scrolling="yes" width="180" height="135">
  <p>Your browser does not support iframes.</p>
</iframe>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16103407/get-html-inside-iframe-using-jquery

Answer (score 0):

The website you linked to also has an `iframe` in it, that links to their Wordpress blog here: http://baronafreeplayonlinepoker.wordpress.com/

You should be using that URL not the one you mentioned.

I would also recommend that **if what you are trying to do is display content for the latest blog post from their website**, which will change as time goes on, then you should be reading their RSS feed found here: http://baronafreeplayonlinepoker.wordpress.com/feed/

and obtaining the first feed item (latest) that way.

Your first option might be to search for a Wordpress RSS widget for external websites, alternatively if you want to be more customised about how you retrieve the RSS, then one way (if your using .NET) is to use `System.Net.WebClient` and `System.Web.WebRequest`, fetch and cache the result and then you can parse the feed using `XMLReader` & `SyndicationFeed` classes.