# How do I get a paragraph from a website and display it in an iframe?

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to get the first paragraph from the website below and display it in an iframe.
Can you correct my code?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var iframe = document.getElementById('iframe');
            $(iframe).contents().find("<p>").html();
        </script>
    </head>

        <body>
            <iframe name="iframe" id="iframe" src="https://www.baronaonlinepoker.com/blog" scrolling="yes" width="180" height="135">
            </iframe>
        </body>

</html>
```

Comment: While your code may retrieve the `<p>` tag's html content, you're not doing anything with it.  You may also need to use a load event on the iframe to ensure that you don't run your jQuery before the iframe loads.

Comment: I tried to duplicate this. I modified your code so it was closer to jQuery's example, and the **jQuery** script (not your/my code) generated this error: `Permission denied to access property 'document'` -- So it might not be solvable this way. Frame security has gotten a lot tougher over the years. I hope this is some small help to you.

Answer (score 0):

You'd be better to use a DIV and use XMLHTTPRequest to set the innerHTML

Answer (score 0):

If the browser loads a page from x.com, that page can have a frame whose source is y.com, but the x.com code will not have access to the y.com DOM. This is a cross-domain issue. You can read more here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy

Answer (score 0):

Please see my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19100553/98706
because I think your going about achieving something the wrong way.