# How get value from iframe?

Tags: jquery, iframe

I have page test.php

when i click on button on this page upload iframe in popup fancybox.

Iframe have select.

I would like that when i change value in select original page get value this select from iframe.

I make:

```
$(function() {
   $("#select").on('change',function() {
      $('.tk').val($(this).val()); // original page have <input type="text" class="tk">
      parent.$.fancybox.close();
   });
});
```

but the value of select not transmitted input in the page...

How make this?

P.S.: `$(window.top).find(".tk").val($(this).val());` not work...

Comment: Duplicate of: [Get html inside iframe using jquery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16103407/get-html-inside-iframe-using-jquery)

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery/JavaScript: accessing contents of an iframe](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/364952/jquery-javascript-accessing-contents-of-an-iframe)

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl me need get not in iframe. me need get data to page from iframe.