# Search for string data from data in an iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net, iframe

I am trying to make a program that can search for elements in a webpage using its source code. (i.e, first I will enter a webpage address to the application. suppose I enter *www.google.com* in the application. Then I will search for `type="text"` and then the program should search source code of *google.com* and show me the number of `type="text"` elements found in source code of Google).

I am using an external tool provided by `iWEBTool` to get the source code.
The code is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>My App</title>
    <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico" />

    <style type="text/css">
        #PageSource {
            height: 367px;
            width: 62%;
        }
        .auto-style1 {
            width: 287px;
        }
        .auto-style2 {
            width: 389px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

  <h1 style="text-align:center">My App</h1>
<form method="get" name="pageform" action="http://www.iwebtool.com/tool/tools/code_viewer/code_viewer.php"  target="pageframe" onsubmit="return validate(this);"><table border="0" style="border-collapse: collapse" width="100%"><tr>
<td width="956" height="91" valign="top"><br />
<table style="border-collapse: collapse" width="100%" class="tooltop" height="76"><tr>
<td><br />
<table border="0" style="border-collapse: collapse" width="100%" cellspacing="5"><tr>
<td height="28" class="auto-style1">Enter the website address :</td>
<td height="28" class="auto-style2"><br />
<font size="1">http://</font><input type="text" name="domain" size="26"></td>
<td height="28" width="391"><br />
<input type="submit" value="View!" style="float: left"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td height="21" class="auto-style1">&nbsp;</td>
<td width="691" colspan="2" height="21" align="top"><font size="1"></font></td>
</tr>
</table></td>
</tr>
</table></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="956"><br />
<iframe name="pageframe" class="toolbot" frameborder="0" id="PageSource"><br />
</iframe></td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
    <script language="JavaScript">
                   function validate(theform) {
                       if (theform.domain.value == "") { alert("No Domain"); return false; }
                       return true;
                   }

<br />
</body>
</html>
```

Now, the source code gets successfully displayed in the web app and it is using an iframe to show the source code. I now want to find a way to search for tags inside the source code which is contained in iframe.

Should I load the content inside the iframe to a div to make the searching possible? Or is there any other way to accomplish searching?

Please help!

Comment: if the iframe domain is the same as your application domain its possible, else you somehow have to get it into your domain only then you can read the DOM

Comment: Any suggestions how to do that?

Comment: It means that you will only be able to access elements in an iframe that's in your own domain, so if the iframe *src* attribute is not in your same domain it will fail to be "queried" because it would be a cross-domain request.

Comment: I am using an online tool to load the source of a webpage in another domain to my webpage. Does that mean that the iframe content is in domain of the iWebTool?

Comment: You said you are using a tool to get the contents right? so just append the content into some div and then you can use jquery

Comment: can you write the code to append it to a div? sorry but im in learning phase and needs example to understand. This is just a demo project I'm working on to learn more.

Comment: There are libraries like HTMLAgility pack which can get you the HTML contents of any site into your C# code.. then you can use xpath to play with the DOM...

Comment: @MidhunT `can you write the code to append it to a div?` I can write a code to append to div.. but what to append?? where do I get the contents from?? if you can show that code may be we can continue from there

Comment: @Reddy - I have pasted my whole code above.

Comment: @MidhunT in your code what happens after you submit the form...

Comment: @Reddy - after i submit the form, an iframe object appears in the same page itself with the source code of the website inside it.

Comment: Ok But what is the Source of the iframe.. Can you check and tell?

Comment: @MidhunT check the source of the iframe using jquery you can get it... see if it is same as your application domain name..

Comment: @Reddy-  When I rightclick on the loaded page and click on 'load iframe source', I get the following link : "view-source:http://www.iwebtool.com/tool/tools/code_viewer/code_viewer.php?domain=www.google.com"

Answer (score 0):

Consider loading the content inside a div as you suggest. As far as I know, you cannot "query" elements in an iframe if I'm correct.

[jQuery/JavaScript: accessing contents of an iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/364952/jquery-javascript-accessing-contents-of-an-iframe)

[Get HTML inside iframe using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16103407/get-html-inside-iframe-using-jquery)

[How to access the content of an iframe with jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1796619/how-to-access-the-content-of-an-iframe-with-jquery)

-

As requested by the question author:

I would create a proxy PHP/Python/Ruby/C#/whatever script in order to fetch the pages from my own domain:

**Note:** I did not try this myself yet, since it's not possible for me, but hey, you could try this in a second. Consider changing the tables for div structures as well. In HTML code, you should replace the */path/to/my-script.php* string with the path to your PHP script.

**Security notice:** The following code is potentially dangerous, be careful.

*Sample PHP:*

```
<?php

echo file_get_contents($_POST["url"]);
```

Then I would just AJAX my own service:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
  <title>My App</title>
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico" />

  <style type="text/css">
    #PageSource {
      height: 367px;
      width: 62%;
    }
    .auto-style1 {
      width: 287px;
    }
    .auto-style2 {
      width: 389px;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>

  <h1 style="text-align:center">My App</h1>
  <form method="post" id="pageform" name="pageform" action="/path/to/my-script.php" ><table border="0" style="border-collapse: collapse" width="100%"><tr>
    <td width="956" height="91" valign="top"><br />
      <table style="border-collapse: collapse" width="100%" class="tooltop" height="76"><tr>
        <td><br />
          <table border="0" style="border-collapse: collapse" width="100%" cellspacing="5"><tr>
            <td height="28" class="auto-style1">Enter the website address :</td>
            <td height="28" class="auto-style2"><br />
              <font size="1">http://</font><input type="text" name="domain" size="26"></td>
              <td height="28" width="391"><br />
                <input type="submit" value="View!" style="float: left"></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td height="21" class="auto-style1">&nbsp;</td>
                <td width="691" colspan="2" height="21" align="top"><font size="1"></font></td>
              </tr>
            </table></td>
          </tr>
        </table></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td width="956"><br />
          <div style="width:956px;" id="loaded-div"></div>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </form>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      function validate(theform) {
       if (theform.domain.value == "") { alert("No Domain"); return false; }
       return true;
     }

     $('#pageform').on('submit', function(){
      if (!validate(this))
        return false;


        $.ajax({
          url: this.action,
          type: this.method,
          data: { url: this.domain.value },
        })
        .done(function(data) {
          console.log("It worked, so we load the data into the div:");

          $('#loaded-div').html(data);

          // If I'm correct, you should now be able to access the elements in the div: eg. access textboxes in the document
          var $textbox = $('#loaded-div').find('input[type="text"]');

          // doSomethingWithText($textbox.val());
          // etc
        })
        .fail(function(data) {
          console.log(data);
          console.log("Something wrong happened. Alert user.");
        });

        return false;
    });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you help me with the code to load the content in the iframe in to a div?

Comment: I will be able to post the code in about 1-2 hours. I am busy right now.

Comment: Updated, give it a try.

Comment: Thank You so much for your help. I was busy with something else. I will try it out today and will let you know the result... Tnx again

Comment: @MidhunT, be careful, do not post this into a production site, as the PHP script will just fetch contents from any resource, such as your local files in your system. I have also updated the HTML document, adding an ID attribute to the form.

Comment: Okay sir, tnx again. Ill update the status as soon as i get time to give it a shot :)

Comment: Renember to mark the answer as correct if it solves your problem. Thank you.

Comment: Sure, I will.  tnx for your patience. I am travelling and I dont have my machine with me now to check. sorry and tnx again

Comment: Sorry for the late update. I tried running the application with your code and I changed the path pointing to my script file. But while clicking the submit button, nothing is happening. So I went to inspect window and found some errors. They are :


Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)


jquery-1.12.0.min.js:4 XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///C:/Users/admin/Desktop/Script.php. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.

Comment: I have updated the JS in order to log the data returned by the error. Post it here for eg.