# How to get HTML from iframe in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, iframe

I want to get HTML code of header from iframe and put it to angular app. It's looks like:

iframe:

```
<div id="event-details-wrapper">
   <div id="event-details">Header</div>
</div>
```

angular html:

```
 <iframe id="welcome-iframe" ng-src="{{ welcomeUrl }}"></iframe>

 {{ header }}
  <br />
 <div ng-bind-html="header"></div>
```

angular js:

```
 $scope.welcomeUrl = $sce.trustAsResourceUrl('http://localhost:63342/welcome.html?id=123');

var html = $sce.trustAsHtml(angular.element('#welcome-iframe').contents().find('#event-details-wrapper').get(0).innerHTML) ;

$scope.header =   html + '<div>Hello</div>' ;
```

And result:

```
 ...</iframe>
      <div id="event-details">Header</div> //just text


      Hello //div element
```

How can I paste HTML from iframe to my app?

Comment: Make sure `$scope.header = html + '<div>Hello</div>' ;` should also use `$sce.trustAsHtml` & double check you have included `ngSanitize` module or not..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get HTML inside iframe using jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16103407/get-html-inside-iframe-using-jquery)

Answer (score 1):

Just do something along the lines of:

```
var targetIFrame= window.frames['targetIFrame'].document;
var iFrameBody = targetIFrame.getElementsByTagName('body');
var iFrameHeader = iFrameBody.getElementById('event-details-wrapper');

$scope.header = iFrameHeader.innerHTML;
```

Comment: When I do this it returns an empty HTMLElement