# How to get all html string from iframe?

Tags: javascript, html

Assume i have iframe contain sample.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="import" href="sample.html">
</head>

<body>
  <p>top</p>
  <iframe src="sample.html" frameborder="0" id="myframe"></iframe>
  <p>bottom</p>
  <textarea cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
</body>

</html>
```

I want to get all content include `<!DOCTYPE html> ...</html>`. I try to search arround the web but what i found only get content from body using

```
var cont = document.getElementById('myframe').contentWindow.document;
console.log(cont.body);
```

I don't want to use AJAX to get content file.
How to get ALL content from `iframe` include html tag?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try accessing `cont.documentElement.innerHTML` to get the contents of `<html>` tag.

If you want also the `<html>` tag, use `cont.documentElement.outerHTML`.

To get the doctype information, try using [`cont.doctype`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/doctype).

```
var cont = document.getElementById('myframe').contentWindow.document;
console.log(cont.documentElement.outerHTML, cont.doctype);
```

You could also use [`XMLSerializer`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLSerializer) if its supported in the browser:

`console.log(new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(cont));`

Comment: `console.log(new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(cont));` solve my problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

Using `document.doctype` to get the document doctype

Using  `document.getElementsByTagName("*");` to get most of the html

https://jsfiddle.net/4hhf6nLm/

Answer (score 0):

following line will retrieve inner html of iframe

> document.getElementById('myframe').contentWindow.document.body.innerHTML

[Check this answer for more information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16103407/get-html-inside-iframe-using-jquery)