# Get the content of the url opened in iframe

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I am showing the url in iframe, now I want to get the content of the webpage opened in the iframe, Can anyone help me with the same. Thanks in Advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get HTML inside iframe using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16103407/get-html-inside-iframe-using-jquery)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get the body's content of an iframe in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/926916/how-to-get-the-bodys-content-of-an-iframe-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

If you want the DOM object for manipulation

```
var nestedObject = $(document.getElementById("iframe").contentWindow.document);
```

If you just want the text

```
document.getElementById('iframe').contentWindow.document.body.innerHTML
```

[Cross reference to original post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16103407/get-html-inside-iframe-using-jquery)

Answer (score -1):

Get the **src** attribute of the iframe.

```
var link = document.getElementById("yourIFrame").src;
```

Comment: OP is asking the content of url, not the url itself

Comment: misunderstanding the question...