# Fetching HTML script of iFrame on console

Tags: html, angular, iframe

I am new for angular 2 and I want to get the HTML of the content which is selected inside the iFrame of the web page.

Comment: Have a look at this https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_element_iframe.asp, and this (its jQuery, but it can help to get you started) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16103407/get-html-inside-iframe-using-jquery. Once you have had a try, you can ask again, highlighting what you have tried, and get a concrete answer. As the question is written now, it is difficult to answer. I would have given an answer with the example in w3Schools.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get the body's content of an iframe in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/926916/how-to-get-the-bodys-content-of-an-iframe-in-javascript)